# Returning multiple values from a function in variables using bash script

Tags: bash, function

I have found the following code to return multiple variables from a function in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
calc()
{
  A=$1
  B=$2
  total=$(( A + B ))
  diff=$(( A - B ))
  echo "$total $diff"
}
read TOT DIF < <(calc 5 8)
echo $TOT
echo $DIF
```

But when I run the script I get the following:

> line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Any ideas how to solve this? 
I have tried the same code in a console and it works, the problem is when I run it from the file: `sh myScript.sh`.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not bash ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: `< <(...)` (*process substitution) is a *bashism* is isn't provided by POSIX shell. You need to ensure you are invoking bash (which your `#!/bin/bash` should do so long as you are not attempting to run as `sh yourscript`). If so, use `bash yourscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *explicitly* running it with `sh myScript.sh`. In that case, the shebang `#!` is ignored because it is a comment to the shell.

Shebangs are detected by the *program loader,* not each individual shell. Were you to run your program it as `./myScript.sh` (assuming it was flagged executable), the program loader would detect the shebang and convert the action to be `/bin/bash myScript.sh` automagically.

In other words, either use the *specific* shell you want to run it with (which would be `bash` in this case), or let the loader take care of it (see previous paragraph).

For example , here's a transcript of your code running with three different methods (specifically `sh`, specifically `bash`, and letting the loader take car of it - only the first one fails):

```
pax$ sh qq.sh
qq.sh: 10: qq.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

pax$ bash qq.sh
13
-3

pax$ ./qq.sh
13
-3
```

Answer (score 3):

You would do it this alternative way to work in non-bash shell:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

calc()
{
  A="$1"
  B="$2"
  total=$(( A + B ))
  diff=$(( A - B ))
  # Return ASCII EOT (code 3) separated values
  printf '%d\3' "$total" "$diff"
}
# Configure the Internal Field Separator to ASCII 03 End Of Text
IFS="$(printf '\3')"
# shellcheck disable=SC2046 # Intentionally split values
# Sets the arguments from the returned string
set -- $(calc 5 8)
TOT="$1"
DIF="$2"
echo "$TOT"
echo "$DIF"
```

One major drawback of calling the `calc` function in a sub-shell within the `set` arguments, is the loss of the function's shell return-code.

It means that it is up to the `calc` function to deal with erroring situations, like a division by zero.

For example: It can incorporate a return code within the returned IFS separated values.

But it means the error handling is much more complex.

I would not recommend implementing multiple return-values this way under non-bash shells.

It is still a valid option for a Bash shell to implement multi-return as an ASCII EOT delimited string, since the shell's return-code is preserved when reading and splitting the returned string the following way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Call calc and parse returned split string into values
IFS=$'\3' read -r TOT DIF < <(calc 5 3)
# Save calc's return-code
_rc="$?"

# The return-code from the calc function is preserved
# and can be tested
if [ $_rc -ne 0 ]; then
  printf 'calc failed with return-code %d\n' "$_rc" >&2
else
  echo "$TOT"
  echo "$DIF"
fi
```